# How to save only the error message in a log file?

Tags: ffmpeg

`ffmpeg ... -loglevel +error FFREPORT=file=test.log`

`ffmpeg ... -FFREPORT=file=test.log:level=verbose`

`ffmpeg ... FFREPORT=file=test.log:level=error`

None of these work.

This works:
`ffmpeg ... -loglevel +error -report =file=test.log`

But it does save everything in the log file and not only the error message, and the log file created contains a different name.

Answer (score 2):

`FFREPORT` has to be defined as an environment variable to work with FFmpeg.
Or you can use `-report` option.

First method could look like this in unix world:

```
FFREPORT=<report-opts> ffmpeg -i input output
```

the second one:

```
ffmpeg -report <report-opts> -i input output
```

`<report-opts>` should, in your case, be: `file=test.log:level=16`

Please notice that `level` option in `report` should have numerical value. Possible values according to [FFmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Generic-options):

```
`quiet, -8’
Show nothing at all; be silent.

‘panic, 0’
Only show fatal errors which could lead the process to crash, such as an assertion failure. This is not currently used for anything.

‘fatal, 8’
Only show fatal errors. These are errors after which the process absolutely cannot continue.

‘error, 16’
Show all errors, including ones which can be recovered from.

‘warning, 24’
Show all warnings and errors. Any message related to possibly incorrect or unexpected events will be shown.

‘info, 32’
Show informative messages during processing. This is in addition to warnings and errors. This is the default value.

‘verbose, 40’
Same as info, except more verbose.

‘debug, 48’
Show everything, including debugging information.

‘trace, 56’
```